# Upon running repadmin /replsummary more than 15 servers are showing "8606" error

Tags: active-directory, replication

We are having an issue with Error ID "8606" ( Insufficient attributes were given to create an object. This object may not exist because it may have been deleted and already garbage collected).

After getting this error i removed the all lingering object by using the following command "repadmin /removelingeringobjects    /ADVISORY_MODE" and then without "ADVISORY_MODE", from the all affected servers.

But still i am geting 8606 error on the same server. Can you plz help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance!

Shubh

Comment: plz do the needfull

Answer (score 0):

Error 8606 is logged when the following conditions are true:

- A source domain controller sends an update to an object (instead of an originating object create) that has already been created, deleted, and then reclaimed by garbage collection from a destination domain controller's copy of Active Directory.
- the destination domain controller was configured to run in strict replication consistency.

If the destination domain controller was configured to use loose replication consistency, the object would have been "reanimated" on the destination domain controller's copy of the directory. Specific variations that can cause error are 8606 documented in the "More Information" section. However, the error is caused by one of the following:

- A permanently lingering object whose removal will require admin intervention
- A transient lingering object that will correct itself when the source domain controller performs its next garbage-collection cleanup. The introduction of the first domain controller in an existing forest and updates to the partial attribute set are known causes of this condition.
- An object that was undeleted or restored at the cusp of tombstone lifetime expiration

**When you troubleshoot 8606 errors**

- Although error 8606 is logged on the *destination* domain controller, the problem object that is blocking replication resides on the *source* domain controller. Additionally, the source domain controller or a transitive replication partner of the source domain controller potentially did not inbound-replicate knowledge of a deleted tombstone lifetime number of days in the past.
- Lingering objects may exist under a lot of circumstances, check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/replication-error-8606) for a list
- Remember to search for potentially lingering objects by object GUID versus DN path so that objects can be found regardless of their host partition and parent container.
- The NTDS Replication 1988 event identifies only the current object on the source domain controller that is blocking incoming replication by a strict mode destination domain controller. There are likely additional objects "behind" the object that is referenced in the 1988 event that is also lingering.
- The presence of lingering objects on a source domain controller prevents or blocks strict mode destination domain controllers from inbound-replicating "good" changes that exist behind the lingering object in the replication queue.

Because of the way that domain controllers individually delete objects from their deleted object containers (the garbage-collection daemon runs every 12 hours from the last time each domain controller last started), the objects that are causing 8606 errors on destination domain controllers **could** (and should) be subject to removal in the next garbage-collection cleanup execution. Lingering objects in this class are transient and should remove themselves in no more than 12 hours from problem start.

So, in short, give them time before debugging. A LOT. Like 50 hours.

Comment: Already i have followed the above steps but after 2-4 days in some DCs, its arises again. I need solution for this.